# exception "Input string was not in a correct format"

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am trying to associate adminID(which is foriegn key) with my table Media. I retrieve the adminID, but when I convert it to int it throw exception "Input string was not in a correct format".

```
void Insert(string name, int size, string path)
{
    SqlConnection connec = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["BloodDonorRegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    string VidInsertQuary = "insert into Media(AdminID,Date,Time,Content,FileName,FilePath,TopicTittle,TopicDescr) values (@ad,@dt,@tm,@cc,@Fname,@Fpath,@TpTittle,@TpDes)";
    string AdminID = "select AdminID from Admin where Email='" + Session["UserID"]+"'";



    try
    {
        int tempid = 0;
        SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(AdminID, connec);
        tempid = Convert.ToInt32(com2.ToString());
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(VidInsertQuary, connec);
        connec.Open();
        com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad",tempid);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dt", DateTime.Now.Date);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tm", DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cc", size);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", name);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fpath", path);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TpTittle",TextBoxTittle.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TpDes",TextBoxDescription.Text);

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("AdminVideoUpload.aspx");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string exp = "Problem occured";
        Response.Write(exp + ex.ToString());
    }
    finally
    {
        connec.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: @MethodMan: No; `ToString()` includes the stack trace.

Comment: that's cool wasn't sure he wanted the stack trace was thinking he only wanted the error message

Comment: what are you planning to do with the following `SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(AdminID, connec);`

Comment: inserting AdminID in Media table as I retrieve it from session.

Comment: You have a SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: the debugger is an amazing tool if used properly..

Comment: @ SLaks so how should I associate adminid with my media table?

Comment: You should create a scalar prop for the `AdminID` query instead of plugging the value right into it, is what SLaks is saying. You did this for the other SQL command. Also, I recommend not using `AddWithValue()`, but instead, use `Add()`. AddWithValue has been known to not always work as intended.

Comment: Thank you @SLaks. My issue is resolved now.

Answer (score 3):

`com2.ToString()` has nothing to do with the query result, and is not a number.

You want `.ExecuteScalar()`, which will execute the query and return the first cell of the result.

Comment: you forgot about `com2`

Comment: with .ExecuteScalar() this exception arise "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@ad"."

Comment: @IbtisamTanveer: You added that parameter to the wrong command.

Answer (score 2):

Here

```
SqlCommand com2 = new SqlCommand(AdminID, connec);
```

you have defined a sql command. You haven't requested it's execution.

So here you don't have any result to convert it into an `int`:

```
tempid = Convert.ToInt32(com2.ToString());
```

Actually, the `com2.ToString()` will return the string representation of the `com2` object whose type is of `SqlCommand`.

In order you solve your problem, you could try this:

```
tempid = Convert.ToInt32(com2.ExecuteScalar());
```

or this:

```
tempid = (Int32)com2.ExecuteScalar();
```

> I had done this earlier and when I try this exception arises..
>   "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the
>   scalar variable "@ad"."

This is another problem in your code, it has nothing to do with the above. 
Actually, this

```
com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad",tempid);
```

should be rewritten to this:

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad",tempid);
```

The `com2` is not a parameterized sql query. Not being it doesn't mean it shouldn't be. You should declare oly paramterized queries in order you avoid the danger of sql injections.

Comment: I had done this earlier and when I try this exception arises.. "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Must declare the scalar variable "@ad"."

Comment: `com2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad",tempid);` is the problem are you sure it should not be `com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ad",tempid);` look at your code one more time.. you are declaring stuff but not using it.. then in the parameters.Add method you are trying to add params to `com2` but you are executing the query on `com.ExecuteNonQuery`

Comment: You're not declaring the `@ad` scalar prop with the `com` object. You must have all scalar properties declared on either the one command object, or both (and I don't think we're sure why you have two of them).